# Merge rows of almost duplicate data in BIRT?

Tags: sql, birt

see the table here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21376096

what i'm trying to do in birt designer is merge those two rows, and combine the Product column cells, since everything else is the same. end result would be a product cell of "IBM Tivoli Asset Management for IT, IBM Maximo Asset Management Essentials"

Would this be grouping? aggregation? would this be done in the SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

This article might help, it goes through a few techniques of aggregating strings depending on what software/server you are using.

You might need to make a function.

[StringAggregationTechniques.php](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php)